# How to chain these two Postman requests

Tags: postman, postman-pre-request-script

I'm new to Postman and I am trying to automate usage of these two requests.
The first one is a POST request which returns a JSON with a single key:value pair ("id") in it
The second one is a POST request which just returns 200 OK

So far I've managed to save "id" from the 1st request's response to an environment variable.

However, I still need to do the following:
After sending 1st request, **wait about 30 seconds, put "id" from first request in the URL of 2nd request**, then send 2nd request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To wait 30 sec use setTImeout in prerequest script:

```
setTimeout(()=>{},30000)
```

This will wait for 30000 second

Now to send the id url you can directly add it to url as {{id}} or in prerequest script add :

```
pm.request.addQueryParams({key:"id",value:pm.variables.get("id")})
```

if you want to run the request again and again till you get 200:

add this to test section of request 2

```
if (pm.response.code !== 200) {
    setTimeout(()=>{postman.setNextRequest(pm.info.requestName)},5000)
    

}
```

**Note:** there is a automatic delay between request option in postman you can use that also.

### Also setNextRequest works only if you run using newman or colection runner

Comment: Thank you, it works. Now can I retry 2nd request a couple of times (with like 5 second pause inbetween) until I get a 200 OK response?

Comment: @damnatus are you doing this manually or through automation ?

Comment: I am using Collection Runner but if it's possible through manually running the 1st request I will be glad to learn it

Comment: @damnatus first request works for both collection runner and manuall but sending again and again request 2 automatically , you should use pm.sendrequest or collection runner . I updated the answer you can try that

Comment: How should I replace the request name in "pm.info.requestName" ? My 2nd request is named just "request 2"

Comment: @damnatus you dont' have to replace it when you keep it in reqeust2 test section pm.info.requestname returns the name of the request itself which is request2

Comment: thank you (I just realized it just means "use THIS request" haha)

Answer (score 0):

In the below image, you can find a delay option before you try to run postman.
This option is used to add a delay between requests running in the runner.

You can check my video to learn more about postman runner and request chaining.
[Postman Runner and Request Chaining Explained in Detail](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0sfdZr3dsWw&t=14s)
[image]